# Unable to use Google.Cloud.Firestore NuGet package in Xamarin for Visual Studio

Tags: firebase, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

I am attempting to add in a NuGet package for accessing Google's Cloud Firestore in Firebase. Adding this package results in the following error:

```
MT0009: Error while loading assemblies: /Users/my_name/.nuget/packages/grpc.core/2.31.0/runtimes/win/native/grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll. (MT0009) (TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS)
```

Microsoft's help page for the error MT0009 is seemingly unhelpful simply telling me to refer to the build output:

```
Building TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS (Debug)
Build started 12/8/2020 1:40:16 PM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target _BeforeCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreCompileImageAssets:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileImageAssets" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreCompileColladaAssets:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileColladaAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _CoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileSceneKitAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCompileTextureAtlases" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCompileTextureAtlases" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCompileTextureAtlases" because it has no inputs.
Target _CoreCompileTextureAtlases:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileTextureAtlases" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCompileCoreMLModels:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCompileCoreMLModels" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreCompileCoreMLModels:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileCoreMLModels" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreOptimizePngImages:
  Skipping target "_CoreOptimizePngImages" because it has no outputs.
Target _CoreOptimizePropertyLists:
  Skipping target "_CoreOptimizePropertyLists" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles:
  Skipping target "_CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles" because it has no inputs.
Target _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj" is building "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

Target ResolveProjectReferences:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj" is building "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj" is building "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

Target ResolveAssemblyReferences:
    No way to resolve conflict between "netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" and "netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51". Choosing "netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" arbitrarily.
    No way to resolve conflict between "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" and "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51". Choosing "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" arbitrarily.
    No way to resolve conflict between "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" and "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51". Choosing "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" arbitrarily.
    Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Google.Apis.Auth, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" from Version "1.46.0.0" [] to Version "1.48.0.0" [/Users/my_name/.nuget/packages/google.apis.auth/1.48.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Google.Apis.Auth.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
    Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "11.0.0.0" [] to Version "12.0.0.0" [/Users/my_name/.nuget/packages/newtonsoft.json/12.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
    Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Buffers, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" from Version "4.0.2.0" [] to Version "4.0.99.0" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Buffers.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
    Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Memory, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" from Version "4.0.1.1" [] to Version "4.0.99.0" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Memory.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
    Consider app.config remapping of assembly "netstandard, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" from Version "2.0.0.0" [] to Version "2.1.0.0" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/netstandard.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
    Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" from Version "4.2.0.0" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll] to Version "4.2.0.1" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2143,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
Done building target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" in project "TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj".
Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target XamlG:
  Skipping target "XamlG" because it has no outputs.
Target CssG:
  Skipping target "CssG" because it has no outputs.
Target CssG:
  Skipping target "CssG" because it has no outputs.
Target XamlG:
  Skipping target "XamlG" because it has no outputs.
Target CoreCompile:
  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Touching "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj.CopyComplete".
Target GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems:
    Target _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromTransitiveProjectReferences:
        __________________________________________________
        Project "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj" is building "/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS -> /Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.exe
Target _DetectSigningIdentity:
    Detected signing identity:
            
      Bundle Id: com.OwlTechnologies.TestAppGoogleAuth
      App Id: com.OwlTechnologies.TestAppGoogleAuth
Target _CopyResourcesToBundle:
  Skipping target "_CopyResourcesToBundle" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration:
      DebugIPAddresses: 127.0.0.1
Target _CompileAppManifest:
  Skipping target "_CompileAppManifest" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ParseExtraMtouchArgs:
      NoSymbolStrip Output: False
      NoDSymUtil Output: false
Target _CompileToNative:
    /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch "@/Users/my_name/Desktop/App Dev/TestAppGoogleAuth/TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone 12-14.2/response-file.rsp" "--gcc_flags=-ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz" 
    Xamarin.iOS 14.2.0.12 (xcode12.1): e0ce49680 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk
    MTOUCH : error MT0009: Error while loading assemblies: /Users/my_name/.nuget/packages/grpc.core/2.31.0/runtimes/win/native/grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll.
            
Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "TestAppGoogleAuth.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2143,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
MTOUCH : error MT0009: Error while loading assemblies: /Users/my_name/.nuget/packages/grpc.core/2.31.0/runtimes/win/native/grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll.
    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.69

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Build: 1 error, 1 warning
```

As far as I can tell the issue is something along the lines of gRPC not being found; however, I am very unsure. I am using a 2017 Macbook Air if that is helpful.

Thanks so much to anyone who can shed light on this issue.

Comment: Can you please try the advice in the log that  `Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file.` Here is the [how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection).

Comment: I have the same problem. have you found a solution ?